# Dokcer build image --secret in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-secrets

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:20-alpine3.18

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .npmrc ./
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=npmrc \
    NPM_TOKEN=$(cat /run/secrets/npmrc) \
    npm ci --production
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Here is my Jenkinsfile and docker-compose

```
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - ./volumns/jenkins/config:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - tasker

  jenkins-agent:
    container_name: jenkins-agent
    image: jenkins/ssh-agent:jdk11
    privileged: true
    user: root
    expose:
      - 22
    environment:
      - JENKINS_AGENT_SSH_PUBKEY=ssh-rsa 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 rulerchen@RulerChen-Desktop
    networks:
      - tasker
```

```
namespace = "production"
serviceName = "tasker-auth"
service = "Tasker Auth"

pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'Jenkins-Agent'
  }

  tools {
    nodejs "NodeJS"
    dockerTool "Docker"
  }

  environment {
    DOCKER_CREDENTIALS = credentials("dockerhub")
    IMAGE_NAME = "rulerchen" + "/" + "tasker-3-auth"
    IMAGE_TAG = "stable-${BUILD_NUMBER}"
  }

  stages {
    stage("Cleanup Workspace") {
      steps {
        cleanWs()
      }
    }

    stage("Prepare Environment") {
      steps {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'NPM_TOKEN', variable: 'NPM_TOKEN')]) {
          git branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'github', url: 'https://github.com/RulerChen/tasker-auth'
          sh 'npm install'
        }
      }
    }

    stage("Lint Check") {
      steps {
        sh 'npm run lint'
      }
    }

    stage("Unit Test") {
      steps {
        sh 'npm run test'
      }
    }

    stage("Write Secret") {
      steps {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'NPM_TOKEN', variable: 'NPM_TOKEN')]) {
          sh 'echo $NPM_TOKEN > npmrc'
        }
      }
    }

    stage("Build and Push") {
      steps {
        sh 'docker login -u $DOCKER_CREDENTIALS_USR --password $DOCKER_CREDENTIALS_PSW'
        sh "docker image build --secret id=npmrc,src=npmrc -t $IMAGE_NAME ." 
        sh "docker tag $IMAGE_NAME $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
        sh "docker tag $IMAGE_NAME $IMAGE_NAME:stable"
        sh "docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
        sh "docker push $IMAGE_NAME:stable"
      }
    }

    stage("Clean Artifacts") {
      steps {
        sh "docker rmi $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
        sh "docker rmi $IMAGE_NAME:stable"
        sh "rm -f npmrc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When i using Jenkins Pipeline，the error message:

```
Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker image build --secret id=npmrc,src=npmrc -t rulerchen/tasker-3-auth .
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

unknown flag: --secret
See 'docker image build --help'.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Clean Artifacts)
Stage "Clean Artifacts" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
```

Because I use private github npm package, i need to use secret to store NPM_TOKEN and build my docker image.
I use lateset and 25.0.3 docker version in Jenkins and im sure that this command can run on my computer.

When i use `docker image build --help` in jenkins, there is no --secret

```
+ docker --version
Docker version 25.0.3, build 4debf41
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker image build --help
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/


Usage:  docker image build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile

Aliases:
  docker image build, docker build, docker buildx build, docker builder build

Options:
      --add-host list           Add a custom host-to-IP mapping ("host:ip")
      --build-arg list          Set build-time variables
      --cache-from strings      Images to consider as cache sources
      --cgroup-parent string    Set the parent cgroup for the "RUN"
                                instructions during build
      --compress                Compress the build context using gzip
      --cpu-period int          Limit the CPU CFS (Completely Fair
                                Scheduler) period
      --cpu-quota int           Limit the CPU CFS (Completely Fair
                                Scheduler) quota
  -c, --cpu-shares int          CPU shares (relative weight)
      --cpuset-cpus string      CPUs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
      --cpuset-mems string      MEMs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
      --disable-content-trust   Skip image verification (default true)
  -f, --file string             Name of the Dockerfile (Default is
                                "PATH/Dockerfile")
      --force-rm                Always remove intermediate containers
      --iidfile string          Write the image ID to the file
      --isolation string        Container isolation technology
      --label list              Set metadata for an image
  -m, --memory bytes            Memory limit
      --memory-swap bytes       Swap limit equal to memory plus swap: -1
                                to enable unlimited swap
      --network string          Set the networking mode for the RUN
                                instructions during build (default "default")
      --no-cache                Do not use cache when building the image
      --platform string         Set platform if server is multi-platform
                                capable
      --pull                    Always attempt to pull a newer version of
                                the image
  -q, --quiet                   Suppress the build output and print image
                                ID on success
      --rm                      Remove intermediate containers after a
                                successful build (default true)
      --security-opt strings    Security options
      --shm-size bytes          Size of "/dev/shm"
  -t, --tag list                Name and optionally a tag in the
                                "name:tag" format
      --target string           Set the target build stage to build.
      --ulimit ulimit           Ulimit options (default [])
```

How can i fix this problem?

this command should not be error.

`docker image build --secret id=npmrc,src=npmrc -t $IMAGE_NAME .`

Comment: What docker version do you have running? I suspect that it might be an older version that doesn’t support the **- - secret** flag. Can you confirm the docker version.

Comment: @OlakunleAbiola 

I try to use 25.0.3 and latest version in Jenkins tool

like this

https://imgur.com/a/9E9onUh

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9QyLitD

I think that 25.0.3 is the latest version

Comment: Hmm, so your Jenkins pipeline is using docker 25.0.3 right?

Comment: @OlakunleAbiola i think so

Comment: I posted an answer as the comments couldn’t capture the options I wanted to propose. Let me know if the answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Olakunle Abiola

This is my solution

```
    stage("Build and Push") {
      steps {
        sh 'docker login -u $DOCKER_CREDENTIALS_USR --password $DOCKER_CREDENTIALS_PSW'

        sh 'curl -sL https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/download/v0.12.1/buildx-v0.12.1.linux-amd64 -o buildx-v0.12.1-linux-amd64'
        sh 'mkdir -p ~/.docker/cli-plugins'
        sh 'mv buildx-v0.12.1-linux-amd64 docker-buildx'
        sh 'mv docker-buildx ~/.docker/cli-plugins'
        sh 'chmod +x ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx'

        withEnv(["DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1"]) {
          sh "docker image build --secret id=npmrc,src=npmrc -t $IMAGE_NAME ."
        }

        sh "docker tag $IMAGE_NAME $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
        sh "docker tag $IMAGE_NAME $IMAGE_NAME:stable"
        sh "docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
        sh "docker push $IMAGE_NAME:stable"
      }
    }
```